# Attemting to run MVC4 site results in HTTP Internal Server Error (500.19) on a 1and1 server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I read almost the all answers about this problem and I still cant figure it out.

I have a 1and1 windows hosting, not a vps, and I keep getting this message when trying to run my mvc4 website:

***HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.***

Thanks for all any answer

Comment: We need a little more information than than to diagnose. Is there a related configSection that it believes is invalid?

Comment: I have a web.config file: [link](http://ry-building.co.il/3144/Web.config)

Comment: do you need any more information?